# How and where do I use AppenCommitMessagetoRunName

Tags: azure-devops, flyway, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
trigger: none # Continuous integration triggers

parameters:
      
  - name: cherryPickVersions
    displayName: 'Scripts To Deploy: Comma Separated List Of Full Version Numbers'
    default: ''
    type: string
    

  - name: buildStage
    type: object
    default: 

      stage: 'Build'
      displayName: 'Temp Build'
      variableGroupName: 'DB Common' #Database.Login, Database.Password, JDBC, Database.Name
      
  - name: deploymentStages
    type: object
    default: 
    
    - stage: 'Dev'
      dependsOn: 'Build'
      displayName: 'Deploy Dev'
      pauseForCodeReview: false
      generateDriftAndChangeReport: false                    #requires check database to be provisioned
      staticCodeAnalysis: false                              #requires python3 installed on agent and pip on PATH
      variableGroupName: 'DB Dev'  #Database.Login, Database.Password, JDBC, Database.Name, Check.JDBC 

    - stage: 'QA'
      dependsOn: 'Dev'
      displayName: 'Deploy QA'
      pauseForCodeReview: true
      generateDriftAndChangeReport: false                   #requires check database to be provisioned
      staticCodeAnalysis: false                              #requires python3 installed on agent and pip on PATH
      variableGroupName: 'DB QA'  #Database.Login, Database.Password, JDBC, Database.Name, Check.JDBC 

    - stage: 'UAT'
      dependsOn: 'QA'
      displayName: 'Deploy UAT'
      pauseForCodeReview: true
      generateDriftAndChangeReport: false                    #requires check database to be provisioned
      staticCodeAnalysis: false                              #requires python3 installed on agent and pip on PATH
      variableGroupName: 'DB UAT'  #Database.Login, Database.Password, JDBC, Database.Name, Check.JDBC 

#    - stage: 'Prod'
#      dependsOn: 'UAT'
#      displayName: 'Deploy Prod'
#      pauseForCodeReview: true
#      generateDriftAndChangeReport: false                   #requires check database to be provisioned
#      staticCodeAnalysis: false                              #requires python3 installed on agent and pip on PATH
#      variableGroupName: 'DB Prod'  #Database.Login, Database.Password, JDBC, Database.Name, Check.JDBC 

variables:

  BUILD_NAME: 'Build'
  FLYWAY: 'E:\Agents\$(Agent.Name)\Flyway\flyway -user="$(Database.Login)" -password="$(Database.Password)" -licenseKey=$(Flyway.License.Key) -outOfOrder=true'
  RELEASE_PREVIEW: 'Release-Preview.sql'
  DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT: 'Drift-And-Change-Report.html'
  DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME: 'Drift And Change Report'
  cherryPickVersions: ${{parameters.cherryPickVersions}}

stages:

  - stage: Build
    pool: $(Agent.Pool)
    displayName: ${{parameters.buildStage.displayName}} 
    
    jobs:
    
    - job: Build
      variables:

      - group: ${{parameters.buildStage.variableGroupName}}
      - group: Flyway.Vars
      steps:
  
        - script: '$(FLYWAY) clean info -url="$(JDBC)"'
          failOnStderr: true
          displayName: 'Clean Build DB'
          env:
            FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED: false
 
        - script: '$(FLYWAY) migrate info -url="$(JDBC)" -baselineOnMigrate=true -baselineVersion=$(Baseline.Version)'
          failOnStderr: true
          displayName: 'Validate Migrate Scripts'
 
        - script: '$(FLYWAY) undo info -url="$(JDBC)" -target="$(First.Undo.Script)"?'
          continueOnError: true
          displayName: 'Validate Undo Scripts'
        
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
            targetFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)' 
 
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact'
          inputs:
            ArtifactName: '$(BUILD_NAME)'
            PathtoPublish: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
 
  - ${{each stage in parameters.deploymentStages}}:
  
    - stage: ${{stage.stage}} 
      pool: $(Agent.Pool)
      displayName: ${{stage.displayName}}
      dependsOn: ${{stage.dependsOn}}
      jobs:
      - job: PreRelease
        displayName: Release Preview
        variables:
        - group: ${{stage.variableGroupName}}
        - group: Flyway.Vars
        steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: '$(BUILD_NAME)'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
        
          - script: '$(FLYWAY) migrate -dryRunOutput="$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\${{stage.stage}}-$(RELEASE_PREVIEW)" -url="$(JDBC)" -baselineOnMigrate=true -baselineVersion=$(Baseline.Version)'
            workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
            failOnStderr: true
            displayName: 'Pre-Release Deployment Report'
            env:
              FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED: true
 
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish Release Preview'
            inputs:
              ArtifactName: 'Release Preview'
              PathtoPublish: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\${{stage.stage}}-$(RELEASE_PREVIEW)'
      
      - ${{if eq(stage.staticCodeAnalysis, true)}}:
        - job: ChangeReport
          timeoutInMinutes: 0 # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
          cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 2 # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' before stopping them
          dependsOn: 'PreRelease'
          displayName: Change Report With Code Analysis
          variables:
          - group: ${{stage.variableGroupName}}
          - group: Flyway.Vars
          steps:
            - script: 'pip install sqlfluff==1.2.1'
              displayName: 'Install SQL Fluff'
              failOnStderr: true
            
            - script: '$(FLYWAY) check -changes -drift -code -check.buildUrl=$(Check.JDBC) -url="$(JDBC)" -check.reportFilename="$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Database.Name)-$(Build.BuildId)-$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT)"'
              workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              failOnStderr: true
              displayName: '$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
              env:
                FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED: false
            
            - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
              displayName: 'Publish $(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
              inputs:
                ArtifactName: '$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
                PathtoPublish: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Database.Name)-$(Build.BuildId)-$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT)'
 
      - ${{if and(eq( stage.generateDriftAndChangeReport, true), eq( stage.staticCodeAnalysis, false))}}:
        - job: ChangeReport
          displayName: Change Report
          timeoutInMinutes: 0
          dependsOn: 'PreRelease'
          variables:
          - group: ${{stage.variableGroupName}}
          - group: Flyway.Vars
          steps:
            - script: '$(FLYWAY) check -cherryPick=${{parameters.cherryPickVersions}} -drift -check.buildUrl=$(Check.JDBC) -url="$(JDBC)" -check.reportFilename="$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Database.Name)-$(Build.BuildId)-$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT)"'
              workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              failOnStderr: true
              displayName: '$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
              env:
                FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED: false
            
            - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
              displayName: 'Publish $(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
              inputs:
                ArtifactName: '$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT_DISPLAY_NAME)'
                PathtoPublish: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Database.Name)-$(Build.BuildId)-$(DRIFT_AND_CHANGE_REPORT)'
      
      - ${{if and(eq( stage.generateDriftAndChangeReport, false), eq( stage.staticCodeAnalysis, false))}}:
        - job: ChangeReport
          pool: server
          displayName: Skipping Change Report
          dependsOn: 'PreRelease'
      
      - ${{if eq(stage.pauseForCodeReview, true)}}:
        - job: CodeReview
          displayName: Approval
          dependsOn: 'ChangeReport'
          pool: server
          steps:
            - task: ManualValidation@0
              displayName: 'Approve Change Report Prior To Release'
              timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 1 hour
              inputs:
                notifyUsers: |
                  [Bidvest]\Project QA Team
                instructions: 'Approve Deployment'

      - ${{if eq(stage.pauseForCodeReview, false)}}:
        - job: CodeReview
          pool: server
          displayName: Skipping Code Review
          dependsOn: 'ChangeReport'
      - job: Deploy
        displayName: Deployment
        dependsOn: 'CodeReview'
        variables:
        - group: ${{stage.variableGroupName}}
        - group: Flyway.Vars
        steps:
          - script: '$(FLYWAY) -cherryPick=${{parameters.cherryPickVersions}} info migrate info -url="$(JDBC)" -baselineOnMigrate=true -baselineVersion=$(Baseline.Version)'
            workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
            displayName: ${{stage.displayName}}
            failOnStderr: true
            
            env:
              FLYWAY_CLEAN_DISABLED: true # clean drops a target DB schema, keep disabled except for build step
              name: ${{parameters.cherryPickVersions}}
              appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

This is where it gets tricky, no matter where I try to add the appendCommitMessagetoRunName parameter, it does not work, the documentation is quite vague.  I assumed I had to pass a name for the RunName as well as set the parameter to false, I just can't figure where to put it in my pipeline.

Your help will be appreciated.  I'm using Azure DevOps Server v2022 RC2.

Regards

Colin

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean `appendCommitMessageToRunName`. This should be defined at the top-most level of the yaml files (basically, no indentation).

So in your example, you can add it just under the `trigger`, like so (I added the `name` parameter as well):

```yaml
trigger: none # Continuous integration triggers

appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
name: My-cool-run-name

parameters:
      
  - name: cherryPickVersions
    displayName: 'Scripts To Deploy: Comma Separated List Of Full Version Numbers'
    default: ''
    type: string
    

  - name: buildStage
    type: object
    default: 
      etc.....
```

This parameter is quite new, so make sure that you are up to date with the release which contained it. It was completed in [sprint 209](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/pipelines/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml).

The full reference is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines). Copy-pasting the template:

```yaml
stages: [ stage | template ] # Required. Stages are groups of jobs that can run without human intervention.
pool: string | pool # Pool where jobs in this pipeline will run unless otherwise specified.
name: string # Pipeline run number.
appendCommitMessageToRunName: boolean # Append the commit message to the build number. The default is true.
trigger: none | trigger | [ string ] # Continuous integration triggers.
parameters: [ parameter ] # Pipeline template parameters.
pr: none | pr | [ string ] # Pull request triggers.
schedules: [ cron ] # Scheduled triggers.
resources: # Containers and repositories used in the build.
  builds: [ build ] # List of build resources referenced by the pipeline.
  containers: [ container ] # List of container images.
  pipelines: [ pipeline ] # List of pipeline resources.
  repositories: [ repository ] # List of repository resources.
  webhooks: [ webhook ] # List of webhooks.
  packages: [ package ] # List of package resources.
variables: variables | [ variable ] # Variables for this pipeline.
lockBehavior: string # Behavior lock requests from this stage should exhibit in relation to other exclusive lock requests.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, I do believe it may be related to the version, mine is Version Azure DevOps Server 2022 (AzureDevOpsServer_20230217.5), and the Admin Console is 19.205.33122.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2022), so my thinking is maybe I am still on sprint 205?  If that's how the versioning works, but I can't find a newer install anywhere.

Comment: It could be that the server version of azure devops is lagging in comparison to the cloud version. So the feature might not be released to server yet...